# Mapping remote api data to view rows

Tags: views, plugins

I created a custom view with fields. I have a client file that pull data from the api, using an endpoint. On my code in the execute method of the view, I have this lines:

```
public function execute(ViewExecutable $view) { 
    $index = 0;
    $data = array();
    $row['vat'] = $data['vat'];
    $row['name'] = $data['country'];
    $row['city'] = $data['name'];
    $row['index'] = $index++;
    $view->result[] = new ResultRow($row);
  }
```

This is a code for testing that responded to a success result:

```
$response = \Cvrapi\Cvrapi::get('12345678', 'dk', 'my project name');
```

I want that those values be mapped as $data[] and assign to corresponding $row[].

And in addition, not only I need to display the inputted values, but also to map other data from the api to my custom fields.

I did some logging from the method above and I get an empty array of fields.